# performance: html <Select> <option> text generation using php function -vs- extracting ready <option> values from MySQL db Table

Tags: php, mysql, performance, function

The list of `<select>...</select>` contains about 100 `<options>`.

```
<select>
<option value="GA">Atlanta</option>
<option value="NY">NYC</option>
...
<option value="DC">WashingtonDC</option>
</select>
```

Which way is much better for the server performance to get that 100 strings to be displayed as select options:

1. call a php function to assign a City to display for each state depending on the option value (php function contains an array of cities to display from)
   -OR-
2. create an additional column of capitals in the db table right near states.

So, by using method `2.`, the strings would be extracted from the db by using 1 SQL request instead of calling a function for 100 times for each page.
Am I right `2.` is much much better for performance? (Now method `1.` is used).

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think Ebay users are poor, once they have to select an option Country/Region among 200+ countries upon registration.

Comment: Lol, I didn't say users are poor, just that a long list is a pain in the ass. In fact, many tried to implement another way of selecting countries, e.g. with an autocomplete form (I couldn't find a couple of very interesting articles I read about it, damn me). Long list are always a challenge while developing UIs, even if a common structure is long since established (and often stands for historical reasons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that in method 1 you're not going to the database at all, but simply iterating over a hardcoded array in a PHP file, it should be faster.

In pseudo code, option 1 is something like:

```
for each state
   render state select item
next state
```

Whereas option 2 would be:

```
retrieve states from DB
for each record in result set
   render state select item
next record
```

You still have to iterate over 100 states - except you're getting them from a database result, rather than an array.

However, in practice, I doubt you'd see a huge difference; as others have mentioned, from a maintainability point of view, keeping things in the database may be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Storing the capitals with the states in a DB is much better than hard-coding the capitals in a PHP array and storing the states in a DB.  You'll prevent errors such as updating the DB and not updating the PHP code.  Hard-coding and using a function to do lookup will probably be marginally faster (you never know how the PHP interpreter will optimise the call).

However, the essential logic, which involves a loop over a set of states and capitals remains the same, so the complexity is the same.  And approach (1) as already mentioned is error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong question asked out of wrong assumptions.

- Asking "if php function is slower/faster" makes no sense. PHP functions aren't fast ot slow. everything depends on the content of the function.
- Do not bug yourself with performance questions until you face the real problem.

As for the question, to store capitals in the database is the only reliable method, from the *right database structure* point of view.

Comment: I used States and Capitals in the example because its easier to explain for this example. The question is not about db structure, but about performance. I  mean, that db table contains only several thousands of rows, does NOT grow and stays permanent.

Comment: It makes no sense performance-wise. And it doesn't matter what size db has and if it grows or not, The proper structure it must have despite of such rubbish details.

Answer (score 0):

I would not put this html-code into your DB. Many hosters out there have a very limited space available for your database.

the "correct" way to do it is to have some kind of template engine like [Smarty](http://smarty.net) and use caching. [see this link for a documenation](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/de/caching.tpl)

Comment: Why a whole library like Smarty to create a list? the question is (wrongly) about overheads and you suggest a big template library like Smarty? Let's put aside the fact that php *IS* a template library, how would using a new syntax help in this? by hardcoding it in the template? Sorry but I can't see how this could be the "correct way"

Comment: it's not about smarty the template engine, but about smarty the html-cache. OP asked whether he should have his html precompiled in the DB or have it compile on every request. the correct way according to MVC is to have the countries in the DB, access them via model, assign them via controller, format them in a template and turn on caching to not redo this process over and over again.